# extract points that describe lines in a drawing

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a black and white image of line drawings that may look something like the following: [image: o]

but can be much more complicated.

I want to convert this drawing into a `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>` (pretty much a contour). Except the problem is i cant simply call contour. Calling contour will give me an ordered set of points which outline this shape. I want ordered set of points (maybe even multiple of them) that will give me back the line itself.

This is very close to the contour problem, except "half" the amount of points are needed.

I have written a method which will find me points that are "connectors", and points that are "endPoints".

So in the example, there are 3 endPoints, and 1 connector.

My algorithm is as follows:

```
get actual contours = [[contour]]
classify points to get [endPoints], [connections] map

criticalSeen = 0
for each contour in contours
     If seen[current point] continue;

     If criticalSeen >= 1
          append current point to currPoints
          seen[current point] = true
     If criticalSeen == 0
         continue

     If criticalSeen == 2
          criticalSeen = 1
          append currPoints to result
          reset currPoints to empty
return result
```

Comment: So, what is your actual question?

Comment: The curve drawn in the picture is in itself an approximation. When you use the word "exact" you want the formula that was used to draw that curve? From the set of points you can only hope to build a good enough approximation of the original formula. Exact - no.

Comment: The goal is that the algorithm spits out [[Points]] such that for each set of points, connecting adjacent points with a line will give me something close to the original input

Comment: The main issue is that I am running into some issues with the algorithm i have described. This is sort of just my best approach so far. I am wondering if there is a better way of accomplishing this

Comment: For example, I think ideally (for the example provided), the algorithm would return a std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> of size 3. One std::vector<cv::Point> would describe the line segment from top left to the connector. One from the connector to top right, and one from connector to bottom middle.